# Bind matrix in lists together

Tags: r, list, matrix

there is a list which I have which has several sublists - in every sublist there is a martix

```
lis[[1]]
               V1         V2
386434 2999996820 0.03302860
386435 2999996860 0.03659760
386436 2999996950 0.02551180
386437 2999996960 0.00188527

lis[[2]]
2 249999983 0.00687375
3 250000122 0.02909420
4 250000225 0.00153139
5 250000301 0.26182100
```

the matrixes are not of equal dimension (same number of cols is true)

how can I without using rbind again and again in a single line or somth...just rbind alle the tables in the sublists to a single large table?

result i

```
               V1         V2
386434 2999996820 0.03302860
386435 2999996860 0.03659760
386436 2999996950 0.02551180
386437 2999996960 0.00188527
2 249999983 0.00687375
3 250000122 0.02909420
4 250000225 0.00153139
5 250000301 0.26182100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`total = Reduce(rbind, lis)`

or

`library("dplyr")
total = bind_rows(lapply(lis, as.data.frame))`

Comment: Good catch, @Arun. They need to be data.frames. Answer modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For any list you can call any function with the list elements as if they were arguments of the function with `do.call`. Hence:

```
do.call(rbind, lis)
```

should do it. Its equivalent to doing:

```
rbind(lis[[1]], lis[[2]], lis[[3]]......)
```

and so on for however many elements there are.